# How to group related set of data members and functions , where only one instance of that group must be there?

Tags: java, oop, object, inner-classes

considier,  I am writing a code for `class GUIManager` of simple MineSweeperGame.

Here,

```
     class GUIManager{
            class GameBoardManager{...}  
            class IconManager{...}
            class BoardMenuBar{...}
            class BoardManager{...}
            class DataManager{...} 
}
```

But the real uneasy thing I felt is,

> I need exactly  one instance of every inner classes. 
>     I made those inner classes only to promote grouping and readability

There is no way to communicate this information(given in blockquote) with the future-developers of this code.

Hence my question is,

Any special type of classes is possible such that only one objects of that class can be created? i.e creating 2 objects will give compilation error. or what I must do now to insist the (blockqouted) information.

Making the scenario worse,

```
public class GUIManager extends JFrame 
 {       
      final GameBoardManager gUIGameBoard;
      final BoardMenuBar menuBar;
      final GameInfoDisplayer gameInfoDisplayer;
      final DataManager dataManager;
      final IconManager   iconManager;
      .....    
 }
```

while accessing the elements, I have to use, `gUIGameBoard.boardButton[][]` , `gUIGameBoard.dimensionOfBoard` , `gUIGameBoard.boardColor` etc...

While accessing in this way, it sounds like.. I have many objects for `GameBoardManager` and here I am accessing the element of `gUIGameBoard`.  But the real fact is there is only one `GameBoardManager` is only possible for a `GUIManager`. This is the similar case to other inner-classes object too.

Hence my question is?
 I must have only one `GameBoardManager` for a `GUIManager`, Whether is it possible to group related items without creating a inner-class. Since, while accessing inner-class object it sounds like I am having many.

Answer (score 0):

If the constructors of all your inner classes are private, nobody other than GUIManager will be able to instantiate one.  Add a comment and this is a reasonable approach.

However, your class may need restructuring - that's a lot of inner classes!